# Какой смысл использовать ООП на PHP?

Tags: php

Какой смысл в ООП на PHP, а именно в создании классов?

К примеру я пишу `main` класс и класс `function`. Теперь, чтобы мне использовать в классе `main` функцию из класса `function`, я должен применить `require_once`.

Для чего тогда писать `class main {}` и создавать ссылку на класс `$d = new function;`?
Ведь если использовать `require_once` или `include`, то вся эта писанина не имеет смысла, нам и так будут доступны все переменные и функции.

Comment: а OOP не в php вы понимаете? Может начать с того, что же такое OOP?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятна формулировка вашего примера, но из того что понял скажу:

**Инкапсуляция** (по-русски: «*сокрытие*») — это свойство объектов скрывать некоторые свои данные и способы их обработки (методы) от окружающей его цифровой среды и, в частности, от кривых ручонок малоопытных программистов, оставляя «снаружи» только необходимые и/или требуемые свойства и функциональные возможности. [Источник](http://avolberg.ru/theory/oop/encapsulation)

Таким образом создавая классы вы должны ограничить его действие до себя самого, а необходимость этого понимается при создании относительно больших проектов.

**UPD:** Благодаря объяснению @BOPOH дополню ответ тем, что *классы* в языках программирование необходимы хотя-бы для логического и семантического отделения методов влияющих на разные части и объекты программы.

Если вы не будете использовать классы и ООП, а количество ваших функций (которые будут просто перемешаны между собой) тем временем перевалит хотя-бы за 50, то возможность поддержки такого кода станет крайне невозможной.

Comment: проще подарить учебник по ООП чем переписывать его здесь, я бы удалил вопрос

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich ну все мы с чего-то начинаем. Может мой ответ и ссылка на источник подтолкнут автора все таки почитать про ООП и ответь на свой же вопрос =)

Comment: @Prvz, объясняю что хотел спросить автор: есть класс, в котором есть функции. Но эти же функции можно написать и подключать и без класса. Так зачем тогда нужны классы? В этом вопрос, т.е. автор просто не понимает зачем OOP вообще нужно

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю что такое ООП и для чего он нужен на C# но на PHP не очень вижу смысла. ну если только приять за ответ .уважаемого Prvz